# mysql script for event monitor to find and kill stuck/old/idle/sleeping db session that meets certain criteria

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for something for MYSQL Aurora database that would allow monitoring of database connections, find idle/sleeping sessions over X time from some user or host and then kill those sessions meeting the criteria. I believe wait_timeout will do something like this but doesn't allow for specifying specific user/host. Could this be done via creating an event or some other way? previously would have script that would query and pull the session info for those sessions meeting the criteria and then kill them and just schedule cron job to run but not sure how to do this in MYSQL Aurora db where dont have cron to run jobs. Have an issue where sometimes users get disconnected from our application and the db session doesnt disconnect and stays connected but idle and wont allow the user to login to the app again until the old session is killed, so is the a SQL script that could be turned into an Event using the event scheduler that could run every few min to check and cleanup old session? if someone has done anything like that in mysql that would be helpful or anything else that could point in right direction

Comment: What MySQL version is used? on 8.0.22 the `performance_schema.processlist` table is available... so there is no problem to query it, get connection IDs filtering them by your criteria, then kill them using dynamic SQL.

Comment: This is for Aurora mysql in AWS, are you aware of any example script to do that and how would be best to do since there is no cron available with this db so was thinking using the Event scheduler possibly. Just havent done before so was looking for some examples or someone who might have used for a similar task